# How to extract the 10 most-frequent and 10 least-frequent of words in python?

Tags: python, format

I get an output after I run a few lines of codes with final line `vocabulary`. It gave me 46132 of different words and show me how many times each words appear in the documents.

I attached the screenshot below of the output. I'm not sure which type of the format the `vocabulary` is. I need to extract the 10 most frequent and 10 least frequent words appeared in the documents. I'm not sure how to do that probably because I don't know the format of the output whether is `str` or `tuple`.

[image]

Can I just use `max(vocabulary)` to get the most frequent word appeared in the document? `sorted(vocabulary)` and get the first 10 and last 10 as the 10 most frequent and 10 least frequent words appeared in the documents?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I had solve this problem, thanks for the reply:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the `k` most common words is trivial using the [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) class:

```py
>>> vocabulary = { 'apple': 7, 'ball': 1, 'car': 3, 'dog': 6, 'elf': 2 }
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> vocabulary = Counter(vocabulary)
>>> vocabulary.most_common(2)
[('apple', 7), ('dog', 6)]
```

Getting the least common words too is a bit trickier. The simplest way is probably to sort the dictionary's key/value pairs by value, and take a slice:

```py
>>> sorted(vocabulary.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[:2]
[('ball', 1), ('elf', 2)]
```

Since you need both, you might as well just sort once and take two slices; this way you don't need to use a `Counter`:

```py
>>> sorted_vocabulary = sorted(vocabulary.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
>>> most_common = sorted_vocabulary[-2:][::-1]
>>> least_common = sorted_vocabulary[:2]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution! It works well for me. However, after I run `most_common = sorted_vocabulary[-10:]` to get the 10 most frequent words, it shows me in ascending order in term of the frequency of words appeared instead of descending order. How should I order it so that I can get in descending order?     Further, may I know what does `key=lambda` mean? Thanks!

Comment: To get them in descending order, you can do `[::-1]` to reverse it. The expression `lambda x: x[1]` defines a function which given `x`, returns `x[1]`; it's used as a `key` when sorting the list, so the tuples are sorted by their values at index 1 (i.e. the word frequency).